# How to implement a queue for HTTP requests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, http

I need to send HTTP (POST) requests to external system but the system has limit on number of requests per second.

Are there any approaches how to implement the queue? frameworks? Spring tools?
How to find a required capacity for the queue?

And one more question is:
A client devise sending a HTTP request has two variants:
1. The client's request is kept in the queue until the system is able to handle the request
2. The client's device retries to send a request until the system is able to handle the request.

Which of these options is preferable?

Comment: Most gateway/reverse proxy can do that I believe. Hide the API behind a reverse proxy, and you should be able to configure it to queue requests to the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Resilience4j's rate limiter. It is intergrated with Spring well.

[Github](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j#ratelimiter)
[Doc](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/ratelimiter)